# Parallax background image loads on every mouse scroll, degrade performance

Tags: javascript, parallax

I am new to Javascript and jQuery, sorry if my question is too dumm...

it's a web page that I was trying to develop with:

> http://119.27.180.212/dk-error/blog.html

Every time I scroll the mouse wheel, the Parallax image loads, too many requests for one image cause the webpage slowing down.

Can see the requests on DevTools -> Network, sometimes it won't repeat the problem, refresh will see those "error" request.

I use :

> https://github.com/pixelcog/parallax.js/tree/v2.0.0-alpha

for my blog page parallax background image, as it loads in the demo page,
and adaptive-backgrounds:

> https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.adaptive-backgrounds.js

for the text color, also in the demo.

As in my html, the script.js is detecting the mouse scroll,
I've tried to delete the parts that requests the image in script.js, but it makes the header show effects gone.

Here is the scroll functions that detect the mouse scroll, I doubt this is the source that coz the "loade many images" problem.

on scripts.js line 132

```js
//////////////// Scroll Functions
mr = (function (mr, $, window, document){
    "use strict";

    mr.scroll           = {};
    mr.scroll.listeners = [];
    mr.scroll.y         = 0;
    mr.scroll.x         = 0;

    var documentReady = function($){

        //////////////// Capture Scroll Event and fire scroll function

        addEventListener('scroll', function(evt) {
            mr.util.requestAnimationFrame.call(window, function(){
                mr.scroll.update(evt)
            });
        }, false);

    };

    mr.scroll.update = function(){

        mr.scroll.y = window.pageYOffset;
        mr.scroll.x = window.pageXOffset;

        // Loop through all mr scroll listeners
        for (var i = 0, l = mr.scroll.listeners.length; i < l; i++) {
            mr.scroll.listeners[i](event);
        }
    };

    mr.scroll.documentReady = documentReady;

    mr.components.documentReady.push(documentReady);

    return mr;

}(mr, jQuery, window, document));
```

I want to keep the parallax effects and adaptive-backgrounds effects, any chance to prevent the js to load image on every scroll move?

Help! please, thank you very much!